# how to host website in azure and email in google apps

Tags: google-app-engine, email, azure

Is it possible to host my website in widows azure using a custom domain (e.g mydomain.com) and have the same domain used in google apps for a mail server? (e.g mail.mydomain.com)?

Thanks

Amit

Answer (score 3):

Yes - through your DNS registrar, point the CNAME records to Azure and the MX records to Google.  Read [Understand MX records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352) for the Google Mail setup and [Create CNAME records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283).